# Error handling Telegram bot

Tags: python, exception, telegram, handle

I am trying to avoid a telegram error. This error occurs when a message is not modified:

```
telegram.error.BadRequest: Message is not modified
```

I would like to make a function to print a message when this error occurs instead the original error message telegram prints. I have tried something like this but does not work:

```
def error_callback(bot, update, error):
    try:
        raise error
    except BadRequest:
        # handle malformed requests - read more below!
        print('Same message')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First of all, if there are no evident bugs, this error could be happen if a user if clicking too fast on a button. In this case it can be easily ignored.**

Assuming you are using [python-telegram-bot library](https://python-telegram-bot.org/) looking at your code, you can follow **2 approaches**:

**1. Ignore the error globally**:

`def error(bot, update, error):
    if not (error.message == "Message is not modified"):
        logger.warning('Update "%s" caused error "%s"' % (update, error))`

but you will still receive on the console:

`2017-11-03 17:16:41,405 - telegram.ext.dispatcher - WARNING - A TelegramError was raised while processing the Update`

the only thing you can do is to disable that string **for any error of any type** doing this:

`updater.dispatcher.logger.addFilter((lambda s: not s.msg.endswith('A TelegramError was raised while processing the Update')))`
 
in your main(). [credits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1398961/jh0ker)

**2. Ignore the error in the method you are calling:**

You can ignore the error in the method you are calling doing:

`try:
    # the method causing the error
except TelegramError as e:
    if str(e) != "Message is not modified": print(e)`

This second approach will ignore the error completely on the console without modifying the error callback function, but you have to use it in every single method causing that exception.

---

**Printing 'text' instead of ignoring**:

i suggest you to ignore the error, but if you want to print a string as you said: you can very easily modify those 2 approaches to print the string.

Example for the first approach:

`def error(bot, update, error):
    if error.message == "Message is not modified":
        # print your string
        return
    logger.warning('Update "%s" caused error "%s"' % (update, error))`

Example of the second approach:

`try:
    # the method causing the error
except TelegramError as e:
    if str(e) == "Message is not modified": print(your_string)`